# How can I create ERC-4337 with the modular pattern of Safe Contract?

Tags: gnosis-safe, erc-4337

I have been looking at samples from eth-infinitism and trying to implement ERC-4337 using Safe Contract v1.4.
https://github.com/eth-infinitism/account-abstraction/tree/v0.6.0/contracts/samples/gnosis

I implemented the following and faced an error where the bundler rejected the request due to the inclusion of GAS in opcode.
https://github.com/tujvyong/smart-account

It seems that [this issue](https://github.com/eth-infinitism/account-abstraction/issues/207) is related, and I think that [FallbackManager](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/v1.4.0/contracts/base/FallbackManager.sol#L74) may be affected.

I know Candide Wallet, Biconomy and ZeroDev have not implemented it this way.
However, I would like to implement eth-infinitism as a first step, as its implementation is so far simple and easy to extend.

The most puzzling thing is that I can't figure out whether it is a well-known fact that the samples in eth-infinitism don't work well compared to each project's implementation, or whether my implementation is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Safe has already has a EIP4337 compatible prototype implementations:

- https://github.com/5afe/eip4337-diatomic/blob/alternative_impl_richard/contracts/SafeEIP4337Diatomic.sol
- https://github.com/5afe/eip4337-diatomic/blob/alternative_impl_richard/contracts/EIP4337Module.sol#L127

*Note: These contracts are prototypes, not audited and not intended for the production use*

Comment: Thank you for sharing!
I will refer to it.